Probability that a poker hand of 5 cards contains at least 1 king given that it contains at least one ace
This problem has already been answered here, but I'm interested in understanding why the following solution is wrong:
$$\begin{align}P(K>0 | A>0) = 1 - P(K=0|A>0) &= 1 - \frac{P(K=0 \text{ and } A>0)}{P(A>0)}\\\end{align}$$
I'm using an expression like $P(K=0 \text{ and } A>0)$ to mean "the probability of drawing no kings and at least one ace." That expands to
$$P(K=0 \text{ and } A=1) + P(K=0 \text{ and } A=2) + P(K=0 \text{ and } A=3) + P(K=0 \text{ and } A=4)$$
where $$P(K=0 \text{ and } A=1) = \frac{\binom{4}{0}\binom{4}{1}\binom{44}{4}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$
$$P(K=0 \text{ and } A=2) = \frac{\binom{4}{0}\binom{4}{2}\binom{44}{3}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$
etc. and
$P(A>0) = 1 - P(A=0) = 1 - \frac{\binom{48}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$
Unless I've done my calculations wrong, this solution is incorrect, but I don't understand why.  Any clarifications would be greatly appreciated!

Note:  the question you linked to is not a strict duplicate.  You are asking for a conditional probability, they are asking for the straight probability that you get at least one $K$ and one $A$.  Closely related, but not the same.

Yes, that's my mistake.  Thank you for the clarification!
